# Interesting result while learning JavaScript. But I dont know why

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I wrote the following code and got no output. Here is the code

```
var a1 = undefined;
var a2 = 5;
if(a1 > a2)
    alert(1);
if(a1 < a2)
    alert(2);
if(a1 >= a2)
    alert(3);
if(a1 <= a2)
    alert(4);
```

There was no alert box that came up which means that the if statements resulted in false. Can I know the reason?

Comment: so at which point did you expect `undefined` to be a number?

Comment: I was just experimenting with the language in understanding its behavior and this was surprise because none of the case was executed. Can i know the reason?

Comment: @Abilash: the only condition which would evaluated to `true` here is `if( a1 !== a2 )`. You cannot compare lower-than and greater-than operators on an undefined value.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle for this snippet  http://jsfiddle.net/BAZQb/

Comment: @Dev: if i feared for down votes, i wouldn't have asked this question (I dont care about them). As I've mentioned in my post, its a interesting behavior and this forum is to help everyone understand these kinds interesting behaviors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript tries to casts the value of `x` to `number` using ToPrimitive (@RobG). Since `x` is undefined, this will return `NaN` which compares false to any value. So it will always return `false`.

Comment: `parseInt` isn't use at all (what if x is a float?). The internal [ToPrimitive](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) is used first (where `undefined` returns `undefined`), the result passed to [ToNumber](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3), where `undefined` returns `NaN`.

Comment: Yeah, to be correct that's true. :) I wanted to show, how you can get the result of the cast manually. Could have put that into a better phrase. Sorry.

Comment: Also, it is a bit more subtle than 'can't be compared to an integer value' -- NaN compared to anything returns false, so you can only check for NaN by asking if myVar === myVar.

Comment: @PhilH That's true, too. I will work on my wording, promise. :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere: Done it for you.

Comment: @PhilH Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: @PhilH—you can only test for NaN using isNaN, since `NaN === NaN` and `NaN == NaN` both return false.

Comment: Well, `myVar === myVar` can only return false for NaN (true for undefined) so it too serves as a test, but you're right that `isNaN()` is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Where expressions using relational operators are involved, the [Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) is used to evaluate the operands, then the result is converted to `true` or `false`.

In the comparison algorithm, step 3a converts `undefined` to `NaN`. In step 3c it says that comparing `NaN` to anything returns *undefined*.

In the steps for say the [Less-than Operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.1), a result of `undefined` is converted to false.

So for the *if* statements in the OP, every test returns `false` since they are all relational operators that all use the abstract relational comparison algorithm and one of the operands is `undefined`.

Comment: Just FYI, in Chrome, comparing an undefined to a number returns false, not undefined. So even if the standard gives undefined I wouldn't count on that. To reproduce, try `var a1;` (undefined), then a1 < 5 (get false, not undefined). +a1 evaluates to NaN as you say, but NaN compares false with everything, even itself. I believe that's just following IEEE754 or C++ (can't remember where the definition is).

Comment: Which is per ECMA-262. The **algorithm** returns undefined, the **expression** returns true or false, e.g. for the [the Less-than Operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.1) step 6 says if the result of performing abstract relational comparison on x and y is `undefined`, return `false`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @jAndy mentioned in the comments, <strike>You can't consider `undefined` keyword as a value/Instance</strike>. `undefined` is not a numeric type. Rather, it's a special value of the property `undefined` of the `Global Object`

That's why the Expression `if(undefined {operator} {operand value})` evaluates to false. But consider the code `if(undefined == undefined)` returns `true`

Hope this Clears the ambiguity!

Comment: @RobG thanks for the correction. I hope the latest edit is appropriate!